# how can a compiler that recognizes the iterators be implemented?

Tags: iterator, compiler-construction, yield-keyword

I have been using iterators for a while and I love them.

But although I have thought hard about it, I could not figure out "how a compiler that recognizes the iterators" be implemented. I have also researched about it, but could not find any resource explaining the situation in the compiler-design context.

To elaborate, most of the articles about Iterators imply there is some sort of 'magic' implementing the desired behaviour. They suggest the compiler maintains a state machine in order to follow where the execution is (where the last 'yield return' is seen). I am especially interested in this property of Iterators that enables the lazy evaluation.

By the way, I know what state machines are, have already taken a compiler design course, studied the Dragon Book. But appearently, I cannot relate what I have studied to the 'magics' of csc.

Any knowledge or differential thoughts are appreciated.

Comment: can you explain that a little more? For example with a source code example that you think would be very difficult for a compiler to recognize?

Comment: and also what language you are talking about - what does "yeild" do, for example?

Comment: C# has a "yield return" syntax.

Comment: Sorry, my referance language is c#.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's simpler than it seems. The compiler can decompose the iterator function into individual chunks; chunks are divided by `yield` statements.

The state machine just needs to keep track of which chunk we're currently in, and upon next invocation of the iterator, jumps directly to this chunk. We also need to keep track of all local variables (of course).

Then, we need to consider a few special cases, in particular loops containing `yield`s. Fortunately, IL (but not C# itself) allows `goto` to jump *into* loops and resume them.

Notice that there are some very complicated edge cases, e.g. C# doesn't allow `yield` in `finally` blocks because it would be very difficult (impossible?) to leave the function upon `yield`, and later resume the function, perform clean-up, re-throw any exception *and* preserve the stack trace.

**Eric Lippert has posted an [in-depth description](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2009/07/13/iterator-blocks-part-two-why-no-ref-or-out-parameters.aspx) of the process.** (Read the articles he has linked to, as well!)

Answer (score 1):

One thing I would try would be to write a short example in C#, compile it, and then use Reflector on it. I think that this "yield return" thing is just syntax sugar, so you should be able to see how the compiler handles it in the output of the disassembler.

But, well, I don't really know much about these things so maybe I'm completely wrong.